# Wanted to create UI interface for Business developer team which contains Test Cases

Tags: unit-testing, selenium, user-interface, testing, automated-tests

I wanted to create UI interface for Business developer team which contains Test scripts which are written in my PC in selenium with c#.

Problem :-

1. Business developer team has no visual studio installed in their PC
   because they don't have licence for it.Now if they wanted to show
   demo of Application to client then if they have UI which contains
   Test scripts which i wrote in selenium.so how could i display those
   Test script on business developers laptop which don't have visual
   studio?
2. Here for demo purpose to client ,Business developer team will
   click on particular test case on UI and run that feature. For
   example ,If Business developer wanted to show Login feature in UI at
   Business developer laptop then that script should run.
3. how can i define connectivity between business developer's laptop
   which don't have visual studio and source laptop which has visual
   studio which contain Test script?

It's kind of R & D work,If anybody has idea about this let me know.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you are going to have to setup some kind of infrastructure to support this. You could achieve this through setting up a build server and making a build plan per collection of test scripts. This is going to let the BDs run the tests, but not look into the tests till the execution is done. You will require proper reporting in order to do so.

What you could also do is use a tool like browserstack. With (I am not affiliated with browserstack what so ever) browserstack you can make every executed test viewable through their recording function and every step of every test will be administrated. This way, you execute the test once, they login into browserstack and check every test, test step, expected results, actual results, screenshots and 30 day history recording of each and every test executed.

Comment: console app is too technical and would not work for the business/product team who will use this. We already have a console app solution in place and are now working on a windows form app. Please see if you can find a solution with a user interface - something simple other than Windows form app.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an IDE to run your tests. The person who wishes to run tests to show off some features of the site should be able to download your test codebase and run it locally from the command line. If they don't want to pass in a lot of flags at the command line, you could bundle the commands into batch or shell scripts.

Comment: console app is too technical and would not work for the business/product team who will use this. We already have a console app solution in place and are now working on a windows form app. Please see if you can find a solution with a user interface - something simple other than Windows form app.

Comment: Why not just record a screencast of the test running? There are plenty of free and cheap options for this.